# File error when running a simple read.csv command in R

Tags: r, csv

When I run `read.csv` [on a dataset](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/msleep_ggplot2.csv)

```
read.csv(file = msleep_ggplot2, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

I get an error message:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : 'file' must be a character string or connection

The `csv` file loaded in r studio and looks good. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: What is the value of `sleep_ggplot2` ?  Is this a valid name/path to your CSV file?  The R error message seems to be saying that it is not.

Comment: You have to quote "msleep_ggplot2" and indicate the extension `.csv` if it is actually a `.csv`. Also indicate the path to the file.

Comment: The dataset was not inside the project :')